# Questions about Bessel function of the first kind and its derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative, bessel-functions

I have a few questions about the Bessel function of the first kind at its derivatives. Please excuse my possible lack of rigour as I am a Physics student.

For a project, I have to solve Bessel's differential equation with the form:

$$ r^2 \frac{\partial^2 R_{(r)}}{\partial r^2}  + r \frac{\partial R_{(r)}}{\partial r}  + (k^2r^2 - n^2) R_{(r)} =0 \text{.}$$

This where my first question starts with the formalism for the shorthand of the Bessel function of the first kind because *WolframAlpha* and the articles I'm working with write the solution as some constant times $J_n (rk)$, where the Bessel function of the second kind is thrown out due to boundary condition $R_{(r)}$ can't go to infinity as $r \to 0$. Does this $J_n(rk)$ shorthand correspond to the following explicit expression?

$$ J_n (rk) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m!(m+n)!}\Big(\frac{rk}{2}\Big)^{2m +n} $$

My following question relates to the partial derivative of $J_n(rk)$ and if it follows the following identity,

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial r} J_n (rk) =  J_{n-1} (rk) - J_{n+1} (rk)$$

where the explicit expression would then be:

$$ J_{n-1} (rk) - J_{n+1} (rk) \\ = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m!(m+n-1)!}\Big(\frac{rk}{2}\Big)^{2m +n-1} - \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{m!(m+n+1)!}\Big(\frac{rk}{2}\Big)^{2m +n+1} \text{.} $$

I would also like to note that $n$ is strictly an integer in this case in order to avoid multivalued points and $k$ is free to be any real number (although I could be wrong on this).

Comment: Isn't the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) satisfactory?

Comment: Frobenius method gives the Taylor expansion, while the Fourier transform gives the integral representation of the Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I've looked at the Wikipedia page and MathWorld but I'm still not satisfied. I've never seen the explicit expression where the Bessel function of the first kind is of the form $J_n(rk)$.

Comment: just take [$(42)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and replace $x$ with $rk$, what is the issue?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I wasn't sure if the formalism allowed for that. Would my explicit expressions then be correct?

Comment: It is not a question of formalism, it is just trivial. If $x=rk$, $J_n(x)=J_n(rk)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That hasn't been my experience when dealing with other notation systems such as the Dirac bracket notation. I never saw an explicit version of a $J_n(rk)$ so I didn't want to assume that. Additionally, I'm worried about my explicit form for the derivative.